# Even though Hibernate is added it is not being imported

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, hibernate, maven

This is a SessionUtil of Hibernate where I get errors:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;         //Error in here
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;  //Error in here
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;//Error in here


public class SessionUtil {

    private static SessionUtil instance=new SessionUtil();
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionUtil getInstance(){
            return instance;
    }

    private SessionUtil(){
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static Session getSession(){
        Session session =  getInstance().sessionFactory.openSession();

        return session;
    }
}
```

I have commented in 1st 3 line of code to show you where i get error. Actually i get error on almost any hibernate related command like SessionFactory, Transaction , Commit etc.

However I have added dependecy of Hibernate and mysql Connector.

Dependency that i have added in pom.xml is here::

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.34</version>
</dependency>
```

And in resources i have also added hibernate.cfg.xml::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="hibernateSessionFactory">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
<!--   <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> -->
  <mapping class="com.example.model.User"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Can someone please help me where I am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: clean the project.Might be dependencies are not included in class path

Comment: Are you able to see jars in your classpath?

Comment: Please, paste your stacktrace or your log file so we can inestigate with you the error.

Comment: Yes, all jars are imported in maven Dependencies and I can see all jars even of hibernate-core.

Comment: Do `mvn eclipse:clean` and check

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from your pom.xml fragment, but perhaps you put those dependencies in a `<dependencyManagement>` section instead of a `<dependencies>` section?

Comment: All dependencies are inside <dependencies> </dependecies> section.